# Why all commits gone except the last one?

Tags: git, github

I'm pretty much newbie to *git*. 5 days ago, I've initialized git on a local folder *(named **myproject**)* by this command:

```
$ git init
```

Also I've added all folders/files *(which exists in **myproject** folder)* to the stage by this command:

```
$ git add .
```

And then committed it by this command:

```
$ git commit -m "my first commit"
```

After that, I've set a remote to it:

```
$ git remote add origin https://...
```

And then pushed everything into my repository on github by this command:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

---

From 5 days ago until yesterday, I've committed changes 7 more times.

**Note:** So I had 8 commits until yesterday.

---

Today, I was trying to earn some new experiences about git's commands, and now surprisingly I'm facing with only one commit *(just the last one exists, all other previous commits gone)*. Honestly I'm not sure what did I do. But I'm suspect to this command:

```
$ git push -f origin {token}:master
```

Will it remove all other commits except the last one? If not, do you know what did I do? *(I want to know that because I want to avoid doing that again)*

---

**EDIT:** I'm not sure this is important or not, but when I was playing with commands *(to earn experiences )*, I also have created 1 branch by `checkout`.

Comment: can you show `git reflog`? It shows exactly what things you did.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you for introducing that useful command. I will investigate the result of it.

Comment: In most normal cases you shouldn't use `git push -f`. Normal `git push` will allow you to push new commits to that branch, and deny those commits if they attempt to modify history (modifying history is usually a bad thing, unless you really know what you're doing). Doing `git push -f` essetially says "update the remote branch so that it is exactly what I pushed, even if that means commits are removed from the history of this branch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will `git push -f` remove [some] commits ...?

Potentially, yes.  It depends on precisely what you push.

> Today, I was trying to earn some new experiences about git's commands, and now surprisingly I'm facing with only one commit (just the last one exists, all other previous commits gone).

First, let's note that Git tries very hard never to give up *any* commits, so you are probably OK (as long as you have not removed files from within the `.git` directory itself anyway).

Second, let's take a quick look at how commits work.

In Git, a *commit* is itself a rather small object.  Here's an example commit from the Git repository for Git itself (but with `@` replaced with ):

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 14b1822ef3c838411b7b204e03b7272b8ddd63d3
parent af09003b2897db76cefdb08ab363ed68f2bb295b
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1482859071 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1482859071 -0800

Fourth batch for 2.12

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

That's an entire commit, namely the one whose ID is `e05806d...`.  However, this commit does not quite stand alone.  Note the `tree` and `parent` lines.  The `tree` line gives the ID of another Git object, which I won't quote in its entirety, but will show the top of, to give a bit of flavor:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD: | expand | head -5
100644 blob 320e33c327c6f597bcfd255b13876f21b0b2d8aa    .gitattributes
100644 blob 6722f78f9ab7e9647a3358a52e627f1c9e83f685    .gitignore
100644 blob 9cc33e925de8adc562daf9b176135aba7b5e4d9b    .mailmap
100644 blob 3843967a692d1642e43f536d5e2652b566ca554d    .travis.yml
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
```

As you can see, this `tree` refers in turn to `blob`s, which are Git objects holding the file contents.  That's how the commit stores files: it has a `tree` and the `tree` has `blob`s and maybe more `tree`s, and the `blob`s give the file object IDs, and the names to use in the work-tree when checking out the commit.

The key line to concentrate on here, though, is the `parent` line.  That line gives the ID of another commit.

#### Git works backwards

Git uses these `parent` IDs, which all point *backwards* (from newer commits to older ones), to build what Git calls the "commit graph", or **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or **DAG**.  We can draw this DAG ourselves, replacing each big ugly SHA-1 hash ID with a round `o` representing the commits:

```
o <- o <- o   <-- master
```

This is a very simple, totally linear graph of a repository with only three commits in it.  The name `master`—the *branch name*—"points to" the latest commit.  That is, it has one of those big ugly SHA-1 hash IDs in it.  (The name `HEAD`, incidentally, simply "points to" master most of the time.  If you examine `.git/HEAD` you will see that the file consists of a single line reading: `ref: refs/heads/master`.)

Git uses the contents of `master` (directed there by `HEAD`) to find the hash ID for the most recent commit.  Then it uses that commit's `parent` line to find the previous (second) commit, and that one's `parent` line to find the previous (first) commit.  The very first commit has no `parent` line at all, because there is no previous commit, so the process stops there, and Git can thus show us all three commits.

Again, it simply starts from `HEAD`—which says "look at master"—and goes to `master`, which gives the *latest* `master`-commit ID, and then each of those gives you (and Git) an earlier ID.

#### Your eight commits

With a total of eight commits, we might give them all one-letter names `A` through `H` (which are much easier to work with than 40-character non-obvious hashes), and draw them like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

These are all in your repository, and though I did not draw the internal arrows in this time, `H` points back to `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on to `A`.

If you make more than one branch, though, you get something that requires drawing more than one line.  Suppose, for instance, that you make commits `A` through `E` on `master`, but then run `git checkout -b side` to create a new branch named `side`:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master, HEAD->side
```

Note that at this point, `side` points to commit `E`, just like `master`.  But `HEAD` points to `side` instead of to `master`, and now you make the last three commits on `side` rather than on `master`; and this happens:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
             \
              F--G--H   <-- HEAD->side
```

Now `side` points to `H`, while `master` still points to `E`.  If you `git checkout master` and run `git log`, Git will start by reading `HEAD` (which will now point back to `master` instead of `side`), and then read commit `E`, and then `D` on back to `A`, and you will see only *five* commits instead of all eight.

If you run `git log side`, you will see all eight commits.  This is because `git log` will start not from `HEAD`, but from `side`, which points to `H`.  Note that `F` still points back to `E`, so logging transitions smoothly from `side` into `master`.  In fact, commits `A` through `E` are on *both branches*, at this point.

If you now *delete the name* `side`, this happens:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- HEAD->master
             \
              F--G--H   [abandoned]
```

Commits `F` through `H` will seem to disappear entirely!  But here's a key thing: *they're still in there*.  They are protected through what Git calls a *reflog*.  There is one reflog for each branch name, and one for `HEAD`.  The one for branch `side` is deleted when the branch is deleted, so it no longer protects the commits; but the one for `HEAD` remains, and continues to protect the commits (for 30 days by default, after which the reflog entries themselves expire).

Hence, to locate commit `H`, you can look in the reflogs.  Run `git reflog HEAD` (or just `git reflog`) to see the reflog for `HEAD`.  How will you know which commit is which, when all they have is big ugly hash IDs?  Well, you can `git show` any promising one by its ID or its reflog name, to see if you can find it.  It tends to be a bit difficult, especially if the reflog is full of all kinds of useless leftovers (which is often the case).

You can also use `git log -g HEAD`, which gives you longer output, and that may help.  Or, you can even use `git log -g -p HEAD`, to see them all as patches.

#### What about `git push`?

I mentioned that `git push` might remove some commits.  Let's go back to those graph drawings, specifically the one with all eight commits on `master`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

That's in *your* repository.  But there is another, separate Git repository elsewhere, specifically over on the machine you're referring to as `origin`.  *That* Git repository has some set of commits, and some branch name(s) pointing to the *tip* commit of each branch.  Just as your `master` points to commit `H`, *their* master points to some commit.

If you run `git push` *without* `-f`—`-f` is the "force" flag, and can be spelled `--force` as well—so that you do `git push origin master`, then your Git will send your commits to their Git,<sup>1</sup> and then ask them, politely, if they would please set their `master` to point to commit `H`, just as yours does.

If their `master` points somewhere to the left of `H` (i.e., to any of the commits in `A-B-C-...-G`), it's quite safe for them to make their `master` point to the new `H` commit, because `H` points back to `G`, `G` points to `F`, and so on all the way back to `A`.  That means they won't "lose" any commits.  (The motion from wherever their `master` points now, to `H`, is called a *fast-forward* operation.)  But if they have some other commits that you lack, so that their `master` points to something else—even if it's a bit different—they will refuse your polite request, because that would lose work.  For instance, suppose that instead of `A`-through-`H`, they have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--I
```

You hand them the `F-G-H` chain, which they add to their repository:

```
A--B--C--D--E--I
             \
              F--G--H
```

and then ask them to set their `master` to `H`; and they will say: "no, that is not a fast-forward".  They will leave their `master` pointing to their commit `I`.<sup>2</sup>

If, on the other hand, you use a force-push (with `-f` or `--force`), your Git sends them, instead of a polite request, a demand: "set your `master` to what I say!"  They do not *have* to obey, but they generally will.  If that means losing commits, well, that loses commits.

You showed:

```
$ git push -f origin {token}:master
```

without explaining what you meant by `token`.  The `token:master` string in `git push` is called a *refspec*, and the thing on the left of the colon is the *source part* of the refspec, with the thing on the right—`master`, in this case—the destination.  If you put a hash ID in here, your Git looks up the hash ID, makes sure it refers to some commit in your repository, and then sends their Git a request-or-command (depending on the force flag as usual) to have them set *their* destination name to the ID you specified as the source.

If that's a command, and you use force, and the source ID causes them to lose commits, they will probably lose those commits.

Note, however, that this does not make *you* lose commits.  *Your* `master` should still point to your commit `H`.  The commands that shift *your* `master` name around are `git branch -f` and `git reset` (when `HEAD` points to `master`, that is: `git reset` adjusts the *current* branch, which is the one `HEAD` points to).

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a fairly fancy protocol exchange by which your Git and their Git figure out which commits you have that they don't, and which other objects, if any, they need to get in order to receive everything from you.  The details are beyond the scope of this posting though.

<sup>2</sup>You might wonder what happens to these commits, if the branch is not changed to point to them.  Repositories that receive pushes are generally "bare" repositories, which have no reflogs by default, and these unused objects are supposed to be thrown away immediately (and usually are).  With no reflogs, if you force-push and "lose" a commit, that commit is *also* usually thrown away immediately, so beware!  The lost commit(s) normally came in from *some* Git repository *somewhere*, and if that repository is still intact, those commits are still in it—but you may have to search quite a bit to find that repository.